# How to call web method from external project?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have two projects one is Edge Chamber and other one is Edge Docs. I want to call a web method from Edge Chamber to launch a user on Edge Docs but web method is not calling and there is no error. Please help.
Here is the Edge Chamber code,

```
    function LaunchInEdgeDocs() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:35534/Default.aspx/LaunchChamberUser",
        data: "{userId:'" + userId + "',token:'" + token + "',chamberUserid:'" + cUserId + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, exception) {

        },
        complete: function () {
        }
    });
}
```

Here is Edge Docs code,

```
 [WebMethod]
    public static void LaunchChamberUser(string userId, string token, String chamberUserid)
    {
        LoginUser(userId, token, chamberUserid);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try sending your data in this form:

```
data: {
    userId: userId,
    chamberToken: token,
    chamberUserid: cUserId
},
```